# Jquery function won´t work after XMLHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, xmlhttprequest, handler

I have a div (#div_eventos) that is updated via XMLHttpRequest to update data cointained in it. Also I have a function that executes on keyup in a input text field. This function do hide or show table rows when find coincidences on the search field (input text). But after the div_eventos is updated the function does not work anymore.

Here is the function I want to execute even after div update:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input#search", function(){
                    var filter = $(this).val();
                    var regExPattern = "gi";
                    var regEx = new RegExp(filter, regExPattern);
                    $("table tr").each(function () {
                        if($(this).data('state'))
                        if (
                        $(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0
                        && $(this).data('state').search(regEx) < 0
                        ){
                            $(this).hide();
                        } else {
                            $(this).show();
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Here is the div that is updated:

```
<div id="div_eventos">                
            <table class="estilo_original" width="100%">            
            <tbody>
            <?php       
                for($i=0; $i < count($lecturas_sitios) ; $i++)
                {
                    $cadena_lecturas="";
                    echo '<tr data-state="california">';
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo ($i+1).". <a href='presas.php?sitio=".$lecturas_id[$i]."&tabla=".$lecturas_tabla[$i]."'>".$lecturas_sitios[$i]."/".$lecturas_distrito[$i]." </a> <img src='images/".$lecturas_modo_comunicacion[$i]."' title='Modo de Comunicacion' width='24px' height='24px'>";
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo $lecturas_medidor_marca[$i]."-".$lecturas_medidor_modelo[$i]."</br>".$lecturas_medidor_tipo[$i];
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo $lecturas_flujo[$i];
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo number_format($lecturas_volumen[$i]);
                    echo '</td>';

                    echo '<td>';
                    if(strtolower($lecturas_medidor_marca[$i])=='panametrics')
                        echo "-";
                    else
                        echo $lecturas_nivel[$i];
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                    if($nivel == 1)
                        echo $lecturas_fecha[$i]." &nbsp;&nbsp; <img src='images/".$lecturas_led[$i]."' title='".$lecturas_minutos_desconectado[$i]." horas desde última lectura' width='15px' height='15px'>";
                    else
                        echo $lecturas_fecha[$i]." &nbsp;";
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                odbc_close($conn);
            ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

I've tried updating the event by delegating function (.on) but it still doesn't work. Can you please give me some advice?

Thank yoou

Comment: There's no `id="search"` in the updated DIV.

Comment: I'm sorry the input text with id="search" is outside de updated DIV and this is the code: 
[code]<input id="search" name="search" placeholder="Buscar Presa..."  class="smoothborder" />[/code]

Comment: If you're not creating the search field dynamically, you don't need to use delegation to bind the handler. Are you sure the function isn't executing?

Comment: Thankyou Barmar, indeed the text field is not created dinamically, but when I type on this field it affects the content of the updated DIV, The Div updates automatically every 60 seconds from the server.
So when  the DIV updates for the first time the function does not execute anymore. So do you know how can I do it to jQuery still detect the DIV content after the data update?

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot this so far? If you put `alert` or `console.log` in the function, do you see it?